# Reducing the Quantity of Nested If-Statements

Tags: swift, if-statement

How can I reduce the number of if-statements in this (below) situation? I'm aware of switch-statements but can't imagine how that would help in this situation.

Here's what's happening below:

1. The first IF safely checks for a date stored in NSDefault, that may or may not exist
2. If the date exists (true), it checks if the date is before "now"
3. If the date is before "now" (true), it safely checks for a user preference of On/Off in NSDefault, this too may or may not exist
4. If it does exist, it checks if that its not equal to off
5. Finally, if #4 was true, the function is called

   ```
   //Queue up more quote notifications?
   if let notif_EndDate = (userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate")) as? NSDate {
       if notif_EndDate.isLessThanDate(self.now) {
           if let quoteNotif_Pref = (userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref")) {
               if quoteNotif_Pref != "Off" {
                   quoteNotifications()
               } else {
                   print("Use has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
               }
           } else {
               quoteNotifications()
           }
       }
   } else {
       quoteNotifications()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching in a switch statement:

```
switch ( userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate"), userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref") )
{
    case let (date as NSDate, weeklyPref) where date.compare( NSDate() ) == .OrderedAscending && weeklyPref == "Off":
        print("User has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
    default:
        quoteNotifications()
}
```

You can also chain your optional bindings (based on @Patrick Stephen's answer)

```
if let notif_EndDate = userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate") as? NSDate, 
    quoteNotif_Pref = userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref") as? String
{
    if notif_EndDate.isLessThanDate(self.now) && quoteNotif_Pref == "Off" 
    {
        print("Use has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
        return
    }
}
quoteNotifications()
```

Comment: In your first code example (the switch), what happens if neither NSDefault object exists? Does that cause an error or will it just run "default:"??

Comment: runs default, since the pattern won't match (date was not an NSDate or weeklyPref was not a String)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `guard` statement:

```
//Queue up more quote notifications?
guard let notif_EndDate = (userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate")) as? NSDate
    where notif_EndDate.isLessThanDate(self.now) else {
    quoteNotifications()
    return
}
guard let quoteNotif_Pref = (userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref"))
    where if quoteNotif_Pref != "Off" else {
    quoteNotifications()
    return
}
print("Use has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
```

Note: This is a direct translation of your code, but its not how I would design it. The `guard` statement is there to check if the scope meets certain conditions and return early if they aren't met. Ideally you would have your `queueNotifications()` call at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A first step would involve not repeating the quoteNotifications() call.

It won't reduce the if statements, but it will reduce the else statements.

```
//Queue up more quote notifications?
if let notif_EndDate = (userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate")) as? NSDate {
    if notif_EndDate.isLessThanDate(self.now) {
        if let quoteNotif_Pref = (userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref")) {
            if quoteNotif_Pref == "Off" {
                print("Use has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
                return
            }
        } 
    }
}
quoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `if-let` statements to `guard` statements

```
guard let notif_EndDate = (userPref_NSDefault.objectForKey("notification_EndDate")) as? NSDate else { quoteNotifications() }

if notif_EndDate.isLessThanDate(self.now) {
    guard let quoteNotif_Pref = (userPref_NSDefault.stringForKey("WeeklyQuote_Pref")) else { quoteNotifications() }

    if quoteNotif_Pref != "Off" {
        quoteNotifications()
    } else {
        print("Use has set 'Weekly Quotes' to 'Off'")
    }
}
```